# How do I parse a string consisting of a letter and number idiomatically and efficiently in Rust?

Tags: string, split, rust

I have a string with a letter followed by a number, like "R123". The letter is **not** guaranteed to be ASCII, and the solution should not depend on the utf-8 encoding. How do I extract the first letter from it, while converting the the number into an integer type? And of course I want this to be idiomatic and efficient.

I tried several things: If I use `char_indices()`, I can `split_at()` the position after iterating once, but then I get the first part again. I can also use `chars()` and `collect()` the tail, but that seems to be inefficient.

I also want to handle errors in an elegant way: I don't want to check for every possible combination (letter but no number, etc.), an "all or nothing" result is fine.

Comment: *but that seems to be inefficient* — why do you think that any of your solutions are inefficient? What would make you believe that any answer we give is efficient?

Comment: Is it always a *single* letter? Is the letter always **guaranteed** to be ASCII?

Comment: @Shepmaster: Yes, it's always a single letter. It doesn't really matter if the letter is ASCII or not, but I don't want to depend on utf-8 encoding issues. I'm new to Rust, so correct me if I'm wrong, but it looks like a final `collect()` would go through the effort of turning the tail character by character into a new string, instead of just using a slice of the tail. `split_at()` on the other hand would create two slices, and the first is not needed.

Comment: @dirkt Is it also part of your requirements to check whether the first character is a letter?

Comment: @dirkt: You **need** to know the encoding of the data. Bytes without encoding are as good as encrypted, there's no sane way to extract information out of them.

Comment: Note that "creating two slices" is meaningless because a slice is simply a (pointer, length) pair kept on the stack. Creation of a slice is in-line and can be optimized away by the compiler. If in doubt, use the `--emit=asm` option to check the resulting assembly.

Comment: For information, I have a feeling the problem is coming from: http://adventofcode.com/2016/day/1

Comment: If this is for that, then R or L are the only letters, so it's def only one byte.

Comment: @SteveKlabnik: The point of the question was to learn proper Rust, not to solve this particular problem. I already solved day 1 in Haskell before I attempted Rust.

Comment: Totally fair! I didn't downvote the question or anything, just mentioning it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you do not care about the error, I assume you want a function of the signature `fn(&str) -> Option<(char, u32)>`. You can use the fact that `.chars()` returns an iterator that you can turn back into a `&str` that contains the rest of the iterator:

```
fn parse(s: &str) -> Option<(char, i32)> {
    let mut iter = s.chars();
    iter.next().and_then(|c| {
        if c.is_alphabetic() {
            iter.as_str().parse().ok().map(|i| {
                (c, i)
            })
        } else {
            None
        }
    })
}
```

`println!("{:?}", parse("R1234"))` will print `Some(('R', 1234))`

Comment: How is `iter.as_str()` implemented? Does it detect that it's a tail of a string, and just re-use the tail, or does it construct a new `str`?

Comment: You cannot "construct" a new `str`. `&str` is a string slice, it is inherently borrowed. This way you know no copies happen. The relevant documenation is here: https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/str/struct.Chars.html#method.as_str

Comment: whoops, thanks @Shepmaster. Now it's not so elegant anymore, but still pretty ok.

Comment: Yeah, but if OP can guarantee that it always starts with a letter, then that check can be removed. Or maybe this is a good opportunity for [boolinator](https://crates.io/crates/boolinator).

Comment: @Shepmaster: It's fine either way, I just wanted to understand how to go about this. Nice solution.

Comment: haha definitely. I think I once suggested such a thing to be added to the stdlib, but they didn't like it https://internals.rust-lang.org/t/bool-into-option-closure-yields-none-or-some-closure/1729

Comment: Could always [make the little function](http://play.integer32.com/?gist=264a54ae9bad51237e3607ee587103e4&version=stable), too.